# Could not initialize class com.sun.jna.Native Android Studio IDE Fatal error

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle

I am getting this IDE fatal error from the first time I started Android Studio. On starting a new android application or importing one, I am getting Gradle sync failed error, in my case:

Error:C:\Users{username}.gradle\native\25\windows-i386\native-platform.dll (The system cannot find the path specified).

Answer (score 0):

Try to update gradle version

OR

Delete .gradle/.idea folder from your project

OR

Clean & Rebuid Project